# Can juju be used in other region than the US?

Tags: juju, aws

Is there a way to bootstrap and/or deploy a server in Amazon EC2 not in the US region ?
In juju's constraints, it seems that we can only choose region a, b, c or d which are in the US.
Thanks for help

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing "region" with "availability zone", which come in those single letters?

Comment: No, that's ok with the letters.

Comment: But I was unable to find the "region" syntax.  Whith your helps, I have finally find all the ec2 regions (us-east-1, us-west-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1, ap-southeast-1,ap-northeast-1 and sa-east-1).

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy to different EC2 Regions, which you can specify in the `environments.yaml` file. In your environments file, under your AWS environment, you can specify a `region` key. So to deploy to the Ireland AWS region add the following to the environments file:

`region: eu-west-1`

That will bootstrap and deploy everything in that environment to that AWS region.

See also:

- https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-ec2.html

Comment: JuJu 2.0 no longer uses environments.yaml to configure cloud environments.

Answer (score 0):

With JuJu 2.0 release the ability to set region has now moved to the bootstrap command itself.

```
juju bootstrap [options] <controller_name> <cloud_name>[/region]
```

So for a command to deploy JuJu to US West on a t2.micro instance (Free Tier):

```
sudo juju bootstrap --bootstrap-constraints="instance-type=t2.micro" aws-devenv-controller aws/us-west-1
```

Comment: Wurde's answer is mostly right, except on the order of commands. I just tried it with juju 3.2 and the cloud/region comes before the controller name. `juju bootstrap aws/us-west-1 my-aws-controller`